# How to get location from Google Map after dropping Pin over it

Tags: android, google-maps, location, android-maps-v2

I'm trying to get location from GoogleMap using ImageView over it.
I can drag this Pin image and the position where I drop it,I should get its location.

I'm using framelayout with googleMap as it's first child and ImageView(i.e Pin) as its second child element.

The same like we have in Google maps application.

[image].

Please suggest me, how to achieve this?

My layout file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fetchaddressMap"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/markerRed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
    android:src="@drawable/marker_red"
    android:visibility="visible" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: You can add listeners to marker and get the pinned location from google map.

Comment: hey man why are you using your own marker as ImageButton , You should  use `map.addMarker()` method ,`.draggable(true)` and `OnMarkerDragListener` to the find out the location. You can also set custom drawable marker rather then using this ImageButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you fetch the screen's `rawX` and `rawY` points via a `MotionEvent` object received in an `OnTouchListener`.

With those 2 coordinates you can find the location on the map with the help of a `Projection`:

```
Projection projection = googleMap.getProjection();
Log.e("TAG", projection.fromScreenLocation(new Point(x, y)).toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you tu use the Markers that are already built in with the Google Maps Api, you just need to set the marker as draggable, and add a listener, the callbacks will provide you with all the information you need. Further information is in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker). Also you can use the [Android Maps Utils library](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) to define custom markers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement OnMarkerDragListener class. You can also get the street adress and other informations. Read the docs.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html

```
mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
            marker.getPosition();
            Geocoder geocoder;
            List<Address> addresses;
            geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(marker.getPosition().latitude, marker.getPosition().longitude, 1);
                String city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, city, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });
```

Use android's pins for better and easy implementation. However, if you want to use customs pins then you dont need to add that imageview under the framelayout. Delete that imageview. See [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker) link to see how to customize a marker.

I hope it helps.